# What is inductance of common household appliances

Tags: inductor, inverter, inductance

I am building a diy inverter and I need to calculate required DC bus link capacitors capacitance. But to do this I need to know the load inductance. I did not find any information about how many Henries are in common appliances - for example fan or a phone charger.

Comment: Use sufficient capacitance that any feasible amount of inductance inside a load is irrelevant.

Comment: I've measured PCB transformer primaries that have a magnetization inductance of nominally 90 henries and may range up to over 150 henries. On the other hand, there are some devices that will have an inductance presented at its terminals of less than 50 micro henries. Do you see the problem here?

Comment: Note that "cheap" inverters inherently have less bus capacitance (and poorer regulation circuitry), so can't reliably drive bigger appliances such as a vacuum cleaner. How robust you make yours, will dictate what devices it can reliably power.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "standard" for this and you will find that even among similar types of appliances the value differs.

To find out what type of load your appliances present, you will need to take measurements.